# How do I create a chart using @rainbow-me/animated-charts?

Tags: react-native, expo, cryptocurrency, react-native-reanimated, react-rainbow-components

Am trying to create a chart on react-native expo using  @rainbow-me/animated-charts but am receiving an error despite following their documentation. "@rainbow-me/animated-charts": "^1.0.0-alpha.6", that's the current dependencies that am using.

How do I create the graph or is there another dependencies that can work as rainbow-me/animated-charts.